# how to detect WIFi Disk through SAMBA API in android

Tags: android, wifi, hard-drive, samba

I want to create a application which detect WIFI disk or WIFI portable Drive through SAMBA API .
when we start the application it search for the WIFI disk and display disk name in list view or any view .

user can access those disk.

Thanks in advance